# using data from over network -> short network error stops everything

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to adapt some code from a collegue.
Its purpose is to get data from a folder specified in a textfield. 
This data has to be stored in a database. 
Everything works with data that's stored locally, but if we use data stored in a folder on our server, every tiny network error makes the program stop. 
The code was written in VB, in which I don't really have experience. 
Does anyone have an idea how I can make the code better, so that data from the server can be used?

Thanks!

Comment: I have so many suggestions for improving the code, you'd be stunned. Unfortunately I can't tell you, because you didn't show us any code, so I'm unsure which suggestions actually apply.

Comment: Wel yes, there is, but I don't really know what code can be handy to see, but, I post some! I'm not really comfortable with posting all the code, kinda confidential.. thanks! @ThorstenDittmar I posted some!

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with network communication or even reading a file. This code is not relevant to the question. Please post code that shows how errors in network communication/data reading are handled.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I tried again!

Comment: In the code there are `try-catch` blocks for reading the files, etc. But there's no exception handling for the last block that start with `If (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(pathZTX) = ".ztx") Then`. There could be exceptions there, too. And one improvement: Instead of getting the folder like `pathZTX.Substring(0, pathZTX.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)`, rather use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pathZTX);`

Comment: but further, this should work with data from a network drive? thanks!

Comment: Yes. Both UNC paths and mapped network drives should work with this code. If you actually debug *without* a proper network connection you should see where the problem is.

Comment: Ok, and if network fails for like a second, it should also continue afterwards?

Comment: No, it will not. There's nothing that makes the code "wait" or "retry". You can change it so that it does. At least you should change it so that it cancels gracefully. I pointed out one part of the code that could fail. There could be other reasons, too. Just debug!